# Why can't the method be called?

Tags: ios, swift

I just cloned a project from GitHub, and I added the relevant folder to my project. When I run my project, the animation effect can be displayed normally, but the images on the animation can't be displayed. I have tried re-cloning the complete code, but it still does the same. I'm sure that all the codes and images are completely cloned.

I added a breakpoint, realizing that the func `circleMenu` is never called.
Can someone please explain this, or at least tell me what I need to write to get it correct?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

import CircleMenu

extension UIColor {
    static func color(_ red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: Float) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: 1.0 / 255.0 * CGFloat(red),
            green: 1.0 / 255.0 * CGFloat(green),
            blue: 1.0 / 255.0 * CGFloat(blue),
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CircleMenuDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    @IBAction func to2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: Bundle.main)
        let view2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view2")
        layerTransition(animTye: .cube, subType: .ramdom, curve: .EaseInEaseOut, duration: 0.4, layer: (self.view.window?.layer)!)
        self.present(view2,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
    //    let secondView = ViewController()
    @IBAction func toView2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: Bundle.main)
        let secondViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        layerTransition(animTye: .cube, subType: .ramdom, curve: .EaseInEaseOut, duration: 0.4, layer: (self.view.window?.layer)!)
        self.present(secondViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
    var imagePickerController:UIImagePickerController!

    enum TransitionAnimType : Int {
        case fade = 0,              
        push,                       
        reveal,                     
        moveIn,                     
        cube,                       
        suckEffect,                 
        oglFlip,                    
        rippleEffect,               
        pageCurl,                   
        pageUnCurl,                 
        cameraIrisHollowOpen,       
        cameraIrisHollowClose,      
        curlDown,                   
        curlUp,                     
        flipFromLeft,               
        flipFromRight,              
        ramdom                      
    }
    enum TransitionSubType : Int {
        case top = 0,               
        left,                       
        bottom,                     
        right,                      
        ramdom                      
    }

    enum TransitionCurve : Int {
        case Default = 0,           
        EaseIn,                     
        EaseOut,                    
        EaseInEaseOut,              
        Linear,                     
        Ramdom                      
    }
    private func animationType(animType: TransitionAnimType) -> String {
        let animTypeArray = ["fade", "push", "reveal", "moveIn", "cube",  "suckEffect", "oglFlip", "rippleEffect", "pageCurl", "pageUnCurl", "cameraIrisHollowOpen", "cameraIrisHollowClose", "curlDown", "curlUp", "flipFromLeft", "flipFromRight", "ramdom"]
        return objectFromDataSource(array: animTypeArray, index: animType.rawValue, isRamdom: (TransitionAnimType.ramdom == animType)) as! String
    }

    private func animationSubType(subType: TransitionSubType) -> String {
        let animSubTypeArray = [CATransitionSubtype.fromTop, CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft, CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom, CATransitionSubtype.fromRight]
        return objectFromDataSource(array: animSubTypeArray, index: subType.rawValue, isRamdom: (TransitionSubType.ramdom == subType)) as! String
    }

    private func animationCurve(curve: TransitionCurve) -> String {
        let animCurveArray = [CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default, CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn, CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut, CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut, CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear]
        return objectFromDataSource(array: animCurveArray, index: curve.rawValue, isRamdom: (TransitionCurve.Ramdom == curve)) as! String
    }

    private func objectFromDataSource(array: Array<Any>, index: Int, isRamdom: Bool) -> AnyObject {
        let count = array.count
        let i = isRamdom ? Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))) : index

        return array[i] as AnyObject
    }
    func layerTransition(animTye: TransitionAnimType, subType: TransitionSubType, curve: TransitionCurve, duration: CGFloat, layer: CALayer) {
        let key = "transition"
        if layer.animation(forKey: key) != nil {
            layer.removeAnimation(forKey: key)
        }
        let transition = CATransition()


        transition.duration = CFTimeInterval(duration)


        transition.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: animationType(animType: animTye))


        transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype(rawValue: animationSubType(subType: subType))


        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName(rawValue: animationCurve(curve: curve)))


        transition.isRemovedOnCompletion = true

        layer.add(transition, forKey: key)

    }


    //    let colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.grayColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.purpleColor()]
    let items: [(icon: String, color: UIColor)] = [
        ("icon_home", UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.57, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
        ("icon_search", UIColor(red: 0.22, green: 0.74, blue: 0, alpha: 1)),
        ("notifications-btn", UIColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.23, blue: 0.21, alpha: 1)),
        ("settings-btn", UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.15, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
        ("nearby-btn", UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.39, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
    ]
//    @IBInspectable var buttonsCount: Int = 3
//    @IBInspectable var duration: Double = 2 // circle animation duration
//    @IBInspectable var distance: Float = 100 // distance between center button and buttons
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    }
    // MARK: <CircleMenuDelegate>

    func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, willDisplay button: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
        button.backgroundColor = items[atIndex].color

        button.setImage(UIImage(named: items[atIndex].icon), for: .normal)
        let image = UIImage(named:items[atIndex].icon)

        // set highlited image
        let highlightedImage = UIImage(named: items[atIndex].icon)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(highlightedImage, for: .highlighted)
        button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    }

    func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected _: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
        print("button will selected: \(atIndex)")
    }

    func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, buttonDidSelected _: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
//        let sb = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: Bundle.main)
//        let secondView = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondView")
        print("button did selected: \(atIndex)")
        if(atIndex == 0)
        {
            if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera))
            {
                self.imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                self.imagePickerController.delegate = self
                self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
                self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
                layerTransition(animTye: .cameraIrisHollowOpen, subType: .ramdom, curve: .EaseInEaseOut, duration: 0.4, layer: (self.view.window?.layer)!)
                self.present(self.imagePickerController,animated: true,completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share sample code with us !

Comment: `let image = UIImage(named:items[atIndex].icon)`, do you have the assets in the project? ` UIImage(named:items[atIndex].icon` returns nil?

Comment: I have follow your step. It is working fine. Please refer this sample source code  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LkxD_CoCJtV556hzXvN6p9ncZu5twZGu/view?usp=drive_open

Comment: Where and how are you using CircleMenu? You import the CircleMenu framework, and have added the delegate methods, but where are you setting the delegate?

Comment: i believe circleMenu are delegate methods and they will never be called until some delegates are not triggered.

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani  Hassan I have posted all the relevant codes,  please check again!

Comment: @Larme I'm sure the assets in the project

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I have posted all the relevant codes below, please check again.

Comment: @andlin I have posted all the relevant codes below, please check again.

Comment: Just a note, do NOT post answers just to add more code or information. Posting answers is for, well... posting answers. Update your original question with more information instead.

Comment: Instead of adding tons of lines of code, show us where you set the delegate (CircleMenuDelegate).

Comment: @andlin I'm sorry,I'm a beginner and I don't know the rules.

Comment: @andlin I set the delegate at the first answer CircleMenu.swift line 7.

Comment: I can see you defining the delegate protocol, but where do you set an object to BE the delegate?

Comment: @andlin at line 21: @ IBOutlet open weak var delegate: AnyObject?

Comment: where is instance for  circleMenu ?

Comment: and then circleMenuInstanace.delegate=self  at suitable place ?

Comment: At line 21 you are declaring your delegate property, but you are never setting it.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you only declare your delegate. Make sure you also set the delegate otherwise your delegate methodes wouldn't be called.